# Restrict to only English chars

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winform with some edit boxes.

The form can be loaded in other languages too, like chinese! 
the requirement is that certain textboxes should accept only English chars
for Example When user types in Tex box 1, it should be in english 
Whereas in if he types in Text box 2 and 3 it should be in Chinese ?

Is it possible to do something like this !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible. You can add a validation event handler that checks the character. You could have a dictionary of permissible characters, or if you restrict the character to a certain encoding (perhaps UTF-8), you could compare the character to a range of characters using `<` and `>`.

To be more specific: You can handle the `KeyPress` event. If `e.KeyChar` is invalid, set `e.Handled` to `true`.

Try this:

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(new char[] { e.KeyChar }) > 1)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: REally good choice, but id go with a list of allowed chars instead, using a foreach... if our char is equal to any of the chars in the list, set the event to handled and return, else set it to false

Comment: In that case, you shouldn't use a foreach. Instead, use `List<char>.Contains()`.

Comment: i used your could and it works great but when i copy-paste it allows it, could you give a solution hint

Answer (score 0):

For handle copy and paste, try the following. It may not be the best solution, but it will trim away non-UTF8 char.

```
    private void Control_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //Prevent the user from copying text that contains non UTF-8 Characters
        if (!e.Control || e.KeyCode != Keys.V) 
            return;

        if (Clipboard.ContainsText() &&
            Clipboard.GetText().Any(c => System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(new[] {c}) > 1))
        {
            char[] nonUtf8Characters = 
                Clipboard.GetText().Where(c => System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(new[] {c}) <= 1).ToArray();

            if (nonUtf8Characters.Length > 0)
            {
                Clipboard.SetText(new String(nonUtf8Characters));
            }
            else
            {
                Clipboard.Clear();
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```